# Управление запросами LoadingObjectManager

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-jsapi

LoadingObjectManager отличная штука, единственное что непонятно - как предотвратить большое кол-во запросов к серверу с метками при зуме карты? Даже если зумить кнопками на сервер отправляется пачка из 5-7 запросов разом с разными координатами. Нельзя ли отправить 1 запрос в конце зума?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LoadingObjectManager так работает. Он кеширует на клиенте уже полученные данные. Изначально он делает один запрос, а в дальнейшем при зуме и драге он дозапрашивает всё, что ему не хватает. Уже полученные области он запрашивать не будет, из-за этого получается, что делается несколько запросов за данными вокруг запрошенных областей.

Comment: Кроме bbox=%b и нужных мне GET параметров там ничего нет. Ссылку предоставить не могу к сожалению( это в локалке.

Comment: у LoadingObjectManager только clusterize: true, у карты center и zoom указаны

Comment: Измените параметр loadTileSize на необходимый вам https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/LoadingObjectManager-docpage/#LoadingObjectManager__param-options.loadTileSize

Comment: Но как это должно помочь? Ведь если splitRequests выключен(а он выключен), карта просит данные сразу для всей области, не по тайлам?

Comment: Я окончательно запутался =( Есть код на который можно посмотреть? Как вы создаёте loadingObjectManager и какие опции у него используются.

Comment: `this.map = new window.ymaps.Map(this.$refs.mapContainer, {
center: this.coordinates,
          zoom: 10
        })

        this.loadingManager = new window.ymaps.LoadingObjectManager(this.urlTemplate, {
          clusterize: true
        })

        this.map.geoObjects.add(this.loadingManager)`

Comment: что скрывается под this.urlTemplate ?

Comment: строка http//example.com/webapi/catalog/task/list?bbox=%b&category_id=0&filter%5Bcashless_payment%5D=0&filter%5Bremote%5D=0

Comment: У меня тут один запрос http://jsfiddle.net/7mghc8p1/ после окончания зума. А у вас?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80698/discussion-between-se0ga-and-roman).